# Разбить сайт на 2 колонки

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

Нужно разбить сайт на 2 части: правая, левая. Есть 5 таблиц, какие-то справа, какие-то слева, сделал через `float:left/right`, но при этом не учитывается размер всех этих таблиц: `div`, в котором они находятся имеет меньшую высоту, можно ли как-либо это подправить? Или только создавать таблицу с двумя ячейками?

P.S Задавать родительскому div фиксированную высоту - не вариант

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понял "не учитывается высота" значит что родительский див схлопывается? тогда вам [сюда](http://css-tricks.ru/Articles/Details/AllAboutFloats)

Comment: Спасибо! Ответ: "Таким образом, схлопывание почти всегда необходимо, чтобы предотвратить трудности в вёрстке. Для того чтобы изменить такое поведение, необходимо добавить элемент отменяющий float после float-элементов, но до закрытия родительского элемента."

Comment: Я так понял эта самая распространённая и самая неизвестная проблема=)

Answer (score 0):

a min-height задавать фиксированный тоже не вариант?
Не совсем понял вопрос, можно ли как-нибудь вживую посмотреть на проблему?